# Best approach to configuration management in spring framework for a project with multiple modules?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a project setup something like this:

```
-common-lib (common lib to included by multiple services)
-event-lib (spring framework 4 (read IOC) library for our event buffer. I want to embed the prod configuration within the app so consumers can use it without configuring it.
-serviceA (depends on event-lib, springboot application)
-serviceB (depends on event-lib, spring framework application)
```

I've been struggling on how to manage configuration in a Java-annotated way.

In the example below (running in the event library as a spring framework 4 project):

- I couldn't get the PropertySource to honor the enviornment's spring.profiles.active
- The environment wouldn't set an active profile even though -Dspring.profiles.active="dev" was specified)

  ```
  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.*")
  @PropertySource("classpath:events-{$spring.profiles.active}.properties")
  public class EventConfiguration {

  @Inject
  private ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

  @Inject
  private Environment environment;

  @Value("${events.asset-processing-queue}")
  private String assetProcessingEventQueue;
  }
  ```

It didn't make much sense to me, since multiple profiles could be activated at once (and that approach to referencing files is dependent on having only 1 set active).

Ideally, I am trying to find a solution that:

- Uses either yaml or a combination of properties files for all the environment properties needed
- Has some sort of intelligent hierarchy of what properties should be loaded. E.g. if I specify a property in my shared lib, honor it unless the consumer overrides it with their own value.
- Can work in a spring framework 4 or spring boot app (we do some stuff with AWS lambda and dont want the spring boot overhead)
- Relies only on java annotation and flat files for the properties. (Prefer to avoid XML).

Comment: Is there an IoC approach to catching the ApplicationContext and injecting new PropertiesSources?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we did it:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/${env}.config.properties")
public class Application implements RequestHandler<Request, Object> {
    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(Request request, Context awsContext) {

        ExecutionEnvironment env = getEnvironment(awsContext.getFunctionName());

        System.setProperty("env", env.toString());
```

This respects the environment property.